# Having trouble getting JS to iterate using each and this

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to identify mp3 files from a list of files and manipulate them, but even though I use "this", my code removes all "b.type" even if it doesnt match the regex

```
//MP3 TIME

$('.secure .content li.file b.type').each(function() {  
    var fileType = $(this).text();

    if(/[MP3]/.test(fileType) == true){
        $(this).remove();//just to see if it works
    }   
});
```

Any help would be fantastic! Thanks

Comment: `/[MP3]/` will match `M`, `P`, or `3`.  So, if `fileType` has one of those three characters *anywhere* in it, it'll match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect, currently it matches all filetypes that contain an M, P or 3. Instead, try:

```
/mp3/i
```

This matches all filetypes that contain "mp3"

The `i` flag makes it case insensitive, so it'll match mp3, MP3, etc